# Execute javascript after composite component has been updated and rendered = "true"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I've made a composite component which is rendered by function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   ...
}
```

When I load the page at the beginning everything works fine, but when I added attribute `rendered="true|false"` and want to switch this component **on** and **off** it makes me troubles, because `$(document).ready(function()` doesn't invoke.

How can I detect from the composite component itself that it's being reloaded and `rendered` attribute is set to `true` (last one I believe should be something like `#{cc.rendered}`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an inline `<script>` (or `<h:outputScript>`) to bottom of the conditionally rendered part of the composite which should execute the desired function.

```
<cc:implementation>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{someCondition}">
        ...
        <script>someFunction();</script>
    </ui:fragment>
</cc:implementation>
```

That function can in turn delegate to `$(document).ready()`, if necessary.